# Upload Frontend Image Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

I have this code to upload an image from Edit Profile page and display it on Profil page:

Code on Edit Profile Page to upload image:

```
echo '<input type="file" name="my_file_upload" id="my_file_upload_id" class="bg_checkbox"/>';

    function register_team_show_case_setting() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting('my_team_show_case_setting', 'my_file_upload');
    }
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    $attach_id = media_handle_upload('my_file_upload', $post_id);
    if (is_numeric($attach_id)) {
        update_option('option_image', $attach_id);
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_my_file_upload', $attach_id);
    }
```

Code to display image on Profile Page to display uploaded image:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_option('option_image'));
```

The upload part works, but when I go to the Profile Page to view the uploaded photo, it shows a URL instead of the image itself, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1luP.png

Should I make something like this to display correctly?
 `<img href="wp_get_attachment_url(get_option('option_image'));"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_option('option_image')); ?>" />
```

You need to pass he image source to the `src` attribute not the `href` attribute, which is meant to send users to a different web page not render images.

Comment: yeah I'm such a noob, switched href to src and now it works, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how can I have a different picture for each profile created with the same user? As of now, when I upload an image, it appears on all Profile Pages - how can I make a different upload image for each profile created?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. To do that will require a lot more information about your program and the specific Wordpress plugins *(I assume)* you're are using to generate these `profiles`. Try asking another question though, with all the relevant information included.

Comment: Do you know how can I make the input button `<input type="file" name="my_file_upload" id="my_file_upload_id" class="bg_checkbox"/>` be submitted without the need to click on a "submit" button? - So as soon as an image is selected, it reloads the page automatically.